# Is it possible to set LoudnessEnhancer for SoundPool

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Does anybody know how to set **LoudnessEnhancer** (API 19) to SoundPool ?
There is only MediaPlayer examples, not pool..

is it possible?

Comment: No, you cannot attach an AudioEffect to a SoundPool.

Comment: pity. Old good equalizer isn't possible too?